# purge or achieve tables in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-design, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a somewhat large project which, a restructuring of the database was planned. (PostgreSQL - Rails 5.2 is used). Currently there are tables that no longer work or that at least were classified as 'useless' or 'poorly created'. Within those 'badly created tables' they make references to tables that do work but that therefore want to give them a better purpose.

I've been searching on the net, and I have a serious divided opinions on what would be the best approach on this case.

**What I've been thinking to do.**

I've been reading, I'm think to achieve these DB and then delete them just in case to have a history on what has been build. Again, I didn't made this DB and It's a task to reestructure them. So my questions are:

Do I remove them completely?

What is the best practice?

What should I know before I can take action to remove them? Can it only be disabled?

Comment: A) Back up *everything* regularly and test those backups. B) Restructure these if possible and migrate the data. C) Preserve the original forms *if and only if* the data cannot be migrated, or there may have been errors in the migration that need to be corrected later. D) Delete them and if necessary restore from backup to fix things.

Answer (score 1):

You should just `TRUNCATE` and then `DROP` the tables that are not being used anymore so you can reclaim the storage immediately, theres no need to recreate the database if you are just removing unused tables, that would be a huge waste of time plus possible added downtime.

If you require the tables to be remade because some specific columns were not being used and they are causing bloat then you will need to create a duplicate table, migrate the needed data to the duplicate data `TRUNCATE` the existing table and move back the data from the duplicate table otherwise Postgres will take forever to clear up the storage leaving you with bloat.